# glGetTexImage returns 0

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

A problem arose: `glGetTexImage` returns an empty byte buffer. In this case, an empty buffer is returned only if you try to get it from the generated image (in this case - a depth map). In other cases (when the texture is loaded from memory) - all is well. Generated texture rendered without problems. Here is the code below.

```
gl.glBindTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthMap.get(0));
ByteBuffer pixels = TextureArray.createByteBuffer(1024, 1024, 4);
gl.glGetTexImage(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL.GL_RGBA, GL.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);

System.out.println(pixels.get(3)); // 0
```

Generating the texture:

```
gl.glBindTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthMap.get(0));
gl.glTexImage2D(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL2.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, width, height, 0, GL2.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL.GL_FLOAT, null);
gl.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL.GL_NEAREST);
gl.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL. GL_NEAREST);
gl.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL.GL_REPEAT);
gl.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL.GL_REPEAT);
gl.glBindFramebuffer(GL.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, depthMapFBO.get(0));
gl.glFramebufferTexture2D(GL.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL.GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthMap.get(0), 0);
gl.glDrawBuffer(GL.GL_NONE);
gl.glReadBuffer(GL.GL_NONE);
gl.glBindFramebuffer(GL.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
gl.glBindTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

I will be grateful for help

Comment: If you want to read from a depth texture, shouldn't the format then be `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT`? And the buffer should most probably only contain one byte per pixel.

Comment: I'd recommend using more than one byte per pixel for depth formats, though, espcially with perspective projection, you won't see much in 8 bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [BDL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2579738/bdl) said, I changed `GL.GL_RGBA` for `GL.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT` and it all worked. The final version of the code:

```
gl.glGetTexImage(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL2.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
```